# Failure to access sqlite entries in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am unable to access the entries of a database in Rails. I would like to print each entry.

My table `courses` looks like:

```
id  instructor name     number created_at   updated_at
1   Smith      Testing  100    2017-02-10   2017-02-10
2   Hong       Web Dev  202    2017-02-10   2017-02-10
3   Roger      Ethics   333    2017-02-10   2017-02-10
4   Sipher     Recess   456    2017-02-10   2017-02-10
```

My controller is:

```
class MainController < ApplicationController
  def index
    #query the model for the data and send to view
    @courses = Course.all  # SELECT * FROM courses
  end
end
```

The view is:

```
<h1>List of Courses</h1>
<ol>
  <% for course in @courses %>
    <li><%=course.name + " " + course.instructor%></li>
      <li>Hello</li>
  <% end %>
</ol>
<p>End of list</p>
```

But my output in browser only shows the header with "List of Courses" and the opening and closing list tags.

**EDIT:**

The populated table:

[image: populated table]

Is my table somehow not completely saved? My controller runs fine and doesn't throw any errors when I call `@courses = Course.all`, so it must be able to see that the table exists, but the controller can't see the rows that I have populated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When rows have a filled in background color, it means they are not saved. Hitting ctrl + s does not save them either.

Right click on an unsaved row and then click 'Submit'. Then the rows will be entered into the table.

[image: unsaved rows]

The correct output is now generated for attempt 1 and 2:

[image: correct output]

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do this:

```
<h1>List of Courses</h1>
<ol>
  <% @courses.each do |course| %>
    <li><%= "#{course.name} #{course.instructor}" %></li>
    <li>Hello</li>
  <% end %>
</ol>
<p>End of list</p>
```

Comment: @Queue can you open `rails console`, and type `Course.all` and post your result here, please.

Comment: I ran `select * from courses` from my sql console and no results were returned to the database console.

Comment: I added a picture of my table. Is my table somehow not saved? My controller runs fine and doesn't throw any errors when I call `@courses = Course.all`, so it must be able to see that the table exists, but the controller can't see the rows that I have populated.